# Is there any lib that recognize object from camera?

Tags: ios, camera, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

I'm currently working on a project which part of it needs some level of AI. End user pointing iOS camera to a pre recorded video, the screen is very large so they can only frame part of the entire video. They can move their iPhone  and shoot any part of the video and the app will automatically recognize what they aiming for and fire a match event.

To sum up

Is there a lib can recognize predefined object from video source?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of people getting [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) to compile on the iPhone.  I am not quite clear on what you will be able to do with it, but I would certainly check it out.

Answer (score 0):

yes OpenCv

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzVXyrIRm30&feature=player_detailpage